# Check if two strings are anagrams - HackerEarth

Tags: c, programming-challenge

> You are given two strings. You have to check if the strings are permutations of each other and output "YES" or "NO" accordingly without quotes.
>
> **Input**:
>   2 lines of input each containing a string. (a to z and 0 to 9)
>
> **Output**:
>   A single line containing YES or NO.
>
> **Constraints:**
>   String would not contain any spaces. size of string < 100

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char sort(int n, char str[])
{
    int i,j,swap;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
        {
            if(str[j]>str[j+1])
            {
                swap=str[j];
                str[j]=str[j+1];
                str[j+1]=swap;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    char str1[100],str2[100];
    scanf("%s %s",&str1,&str2);
    sort(strlen(str1),str1);
    sort(strlen(str2),str2);
    if(strcmp(str1,str2)==0)
        printf("YES\n");
    else
        printf("NO\n");
    return 0;
}
```

How do I make this code as small (shorter code) as possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by small?

Comment: i mean shorter code, lesser number of lines

Comment: Use Ruby.  Then you can squeeze the logic into one (1) line.

Comment: Personally I would prefer faster solutions or more scalable solutions to simply "shorter code."

Comment: "lesser number of lines" is a horrible measure of code performance or quality. Nothing is stopping you from writing this program on one single line. Instead, strive to make programs 1) readable and 2) effective in terms of speed & memory consumption. Whether or not you have to type a lot to achieve those things is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make this code as small (shorter code) as possible?

You could change this:

> ```
> if(strcmp(str1,str2)==0)
>     printf("YES\n");
> else
>     printf("NO\n");
> ```

Like this, using the ternary operator and `puts`:

```
puts(strcmp(str1, str2) ? "NO" : "YES");
```

Technically,
you could also get rid of much of the whitespace and concatenate all instructions on a single line with semicolons.
But that's probably not what you *really* want.

If your aim is simplicity, then I think this is about as simple and short as it gets.

For readability, it would be better to add spaces around operators, for example like this:

```
    if (str[j] > str[j+1])
    {
        swap = str[j];
        str[j] = str[j+1];
        str[j+1] = swap;
    }
```

Some minor final remarks:

- bubble sort is a slow sorting algorithm, but with words of max 100 letters, it's probably good enough
- uppercase and lowercase letters will be treated differently, but since the treatment of letter case is unspecified, that might be fine too